Can I use "Member, IEEE" as my affiliation for publishing papers?
I work in industry but I would like to publish some papers in arXiv, IEEE etc. The work I do is not related and not affiliated to my employer. At the same time I'm not studying / associated with any university. However I do hold active IEEE membership but I'm not a Senior / Fellow / Life member in IEEE.
With above said, Can I use "Member, IEEE" as my affiliation while publishing academic papers ?

Are you required to provide an affiliation?

The affiliation represents where the work was done. Your work was not done at IEEE, so you should not list it.

@Aruralreader At least on arXiv or any other general IEEE form I see, they make affiliation as a mandatory field. Hence I assume there has to be some form of affiliation to have some credibility for those publishing houses to accept the submission.

@R1NaNo - I see your point. So affiliation strictly means either where the work for performed (i.e where the intellectual property belongs to) or where it was supported by any means. Got it.

When publishing in IEEE journals, the author's IEEE member rank and year of advancement is listed in the bio. That's only for IEEE journals. Other societies may do something similar, again with the author's status within their society.

@ViswaKumar "independent researcher", "private researcher", "private investigator" or you can create a research company and list it. Kumar Research Ltd.

I would if I were reading a preprint somewhere or reviewing a submission see listing an association membership like this as an affiliation as a pretty big red flag. Simply listing no affiliation would be much more normal and less likely to get a negative reaction.

Why is it a red flag?

@AndrewLeach Three reasons. 1) affiliations are generally for institutions where on actually did work at or were supported by. That doesn't apply to an association member, so it is misunderstanding what that normally means.  2) It looks desperate to have some sort of official affiliation. 3) At a meta level, it suggests that one did not have anyone else look at it, since anyone in the field would likely suggest as one of their first things for you to remove it.

Thank you. I think this answers my direct question as to whether am I allowed to use "Member, IEEE" as affiliation. Does that mean that, for all the papers where "Senior Member, IEEE" was listed against the author, they either got support "from" / performed the work "with" IEEE ?

@ViswaKumar, I've never seen that listed, but I would guess so.

@ViswaKumar I don't know if this is universal, but in one submission we made to an IEEE journal the IEEE membership tag for one of the authors (such as "Senior Member, IEEE") was added by the journal copyeditors after we submitted the final manuscript to them. We did not add it ourselves.
